# how to transform a nested mongodb table into spark dataframe

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a nested mongodb talbe and its document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "35228334dbd1090f6117c5a0011b56b0",
    "brasidas" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "buy",
            "value" : 859193
        }
    ],
    "crawl_time" : NumberLong(1526296211997),
    "date" : "2018-05-11",
    "id" : "44874f4c8c677087bcd5f829b2843e66",
    "initNumber" : 0,
    "repurchase" : 0,
    "source_url" : "http://query.sse.com.cn/commonQuery.do?jsonCallBack=jQuery11120015170331124618408_1526262411932&isPagination=true&sqlId=COMMON_SSE_SCSJ_CJGK_ZQZYSHG_JYSLMX_L&beginDate&endDate&securityCode&pageHelp.pageNo=1&pageHelp.beginPage=1&pageHelp.cacheSize=1&pageHelp.endPage=1&pageHelp.pageSize=25",
    "stockCode" : "600020",
    "stockName" : "ZYGS",
    "type" : "SSE"
}
```

i want to transform it into spark dataframe,and extract the title "`key`"and "`value` " of "*brasidas*"  as single column respectively.just like follows:

```
initNumber  repurchase  key  value   stockName    type    date
    50000      50000    buy  286698    shgf       SSE   2015/3/30
```

but there is a problem with the form of  title "brasidas",it have three forms:

```
  [{ "key" : "buy", "value" : 286698 }] 

  [{ "value" : 15311500, "key" : "buy_free" }, { "value" : 0, "key" : "buy_limited" }]

  [{ "key" :    ""buy_free" " }, { "key" : "buy_limited" }]
```

so when i use scala to define a *StructType*, it's not suitable for every document,i can only take "*brasidas*" as a single column and failed to divide it by the "key" .this is what i get:

```
 initNumber   repurchase     brasidas     stockName    type   date
  50000        50000    [{ "key" : "buy", "value" : 286698 }]   shgf    SSE 2015/3/30
```

This is the code for getting mongodb document:

```
val readpledge =ReadConfig(Map("uri"-> (mongouri_beehive+".pledge")))    
val pledge = getMongoDB.readCollection(sc, readpledge,"initNumber","repurchase","brasidas","stockName","type","date")
                   .selectExpr("cast(initNumber as int) initNumber", "cast(repurchase as int) repurchase","brasidas","stockName","type","date")
```

Comment: can you share some code you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `df.printSchema()` you'll probably be able to observe that `brasidas` got `ArrayType`.  Most likely (array of map).
So, I'd suggest to implement some sort of UDF function that get Array as parameter and transform it in a way you need.

`def arrayProcess(arr: Seq[AnyRef]): Seq[AnyRef] = ???`